# SpringBoot error al crear Api Rest

Tags: java, spring-boot

Estoy aprendiendo a utilizar SpringBoot y no logro hacer que funcione con las clases que creé, les dejo el código por si pueden ayudar o bien pasar algún *link* de un tutorial o video que explique de forma sencilla la utilización del framework.

```
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicLong;

@RestController
public class CorreoController {
    private final AtomicLong counter = new AtomicLong();

    @RequestMapping(value = "/correo/nuevo",method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseBody
    public String correo (@PathVariable(value = "from") String from, 
    @PathVariable(value = "to") String to, @PathVariable(value = 
    "asunto")String asunto, @PathVariable(value = "texto") String texto){
        Correo correito = new Correo(from,to,asunto,texto);
        return correito.toString();
    }
```

Comment: Buenas, tal y como está la pregunta es un poco amplia pero te puedo responder. ¿Podrías indicar el error que te da exactamente antes de ponerte la respuesta?

Comment: Tiene toda la pinta de que estás usando mal la anotación `@PathVariable`, confundiéndola con `@RequestParam`

Comment: Por cierto, si haces una aplicación REST, GET es para obtener datos y POST para crearlos

Comment: Has editado tu pregunta con posterioridad a haber aceptado una respuesta modificando el sentido de tu pregunta, lo que va en contra de la filosofía del sitio. Por un lado, esto hace que la respuesta aceptada pierda significado, y por otro es menos probable que recibas respuesta ya que al tener una solución aceptada tu pregunta es menos visible. He revertido la pregunta al estado original y si tienes una nueva duda, lo que debes hacer es [Formular una pregunta nueva](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). Un saludo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Vamos a asumir que ya tenemos la configuración previa del proyecto hecha y hemos añadido las dependencias web dentro de nuestro pom.xml.

Imaginemos que queremos crear un endpoint siguiente una arquitectura rest por lo que hemos definido que el nombre de nuestro recurso es coffee y estamos realizando una operación GET para traer datos sobre este recurso, el endpoint sería el siguiente:

```
www.miurlfavorita.com/coffee/{id}
```

donde `{id}` es un número que identifica a nuestro recurso y viene a ser lo mismo que spring mapea en nuestra etiqueta `@PathVariable`. Para realizar este mapeo correctamente, en nuestro controlador definimos el método que genera el endpoint:

```
@ResponseBody
@GetMapping(produces = [MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE], value = '/{idCoffee}')
CoffeeResponse getCoffeeInfo(
    @PathVariable('idCoffee') String idCoffee
) {
//Lógica que hace lo que sea
}
```

Analicemos este método por un momento, si te fijas en el código que has compartido, usas la etiqueta `@PathVariable` pero en tu `@RequestMapping` no indicas dentro del endpoint donde están esas variables por lo que Spring no sabe de donde vienen. Si te fijas en el método uso la etiqueta `@GetMapping` que hace lo mismo que `@RequestMapping` pero por defecto el método http ya es get lo que resulta mucho más legible y te recomiendo su uso (también existen `@PostMapping`, `@PutMapping`...etc).

Dentro del `@getMApping` puedes ver que tengo el `{idCoffee}` entre llaves lo que le indica a Spring que en esta parte de la url lo que viene no es el literal "idCoffee", viene una "path variable" que tiene que mapear en el parámetro correspondiente.

Por último, dentro de la url que he definido, ¿dónde indico a Spring el /coffee que indica el nombre del recurso? esto lo indico en la clase y no en el método ya que no es una buena práctica. Lo ideal sería que cada controlador haga referencia a un recurso determinado y todos los métodos sean distintas operaciones sobre el mismo por lo que mi clase quedaría definida así.

```
@RequestMapping(value = '/coffee')
@RestController
class BestCoffeeClassEver {
...    
}
```

En este caso si utilizo el `@RequestMapping` sin ningún tipo de operación ya que estoy a nivel de clase así que todos los endpoint que genere en esa clase serán url/coffee/(lo que sea que genere en cada método).

Comment: estoy comprendiendo un poco mas gracias a tu explicación, ahora lo hice así RestController
public class CorreoController {
    private final AtomicLong counter = new AtomicLong();

    ResponseBody
    GetMapping(produces = [MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE],value = '/{from}')
    Correo correo (PathVariable('from')String from ){

        Correo e = new Correo(from);

        System.out.println(e.getFrom());


    } lo que no termino de comprender es como llamo a los métodos que tiene cada clase creada...

Comment: ya pude hacer funcionar la creación de objetos...

Comment: y para llamar a métodos de otras clases que anotaciones hay que usar?

Comment: @MaxiHernandez para respetar el correcto funcionamiento de la página, lo ideal sería que la nueva pregunta la pusieras en una nueva publicación y si quieres me la comentas por aquí y te la respondo.